# How to properly save and load an intermediate model in Keras?

Tags: neural-network, keras, computer-vision, image-recognition, convolutional-neural-network

I'm working with a model that involves 3 stages of 'nesting' of models in Keras.

Conceptually the first is a transfer learning CNN model, for example MobileNetV2. (Model 1) This is then wrapped by a model that consists of a small DNN. (Model 2) Finally during training these are all wrapped by a model that concatenates multiple outputs from model 2, calculates loss, and then backpropagates into model 2 and in the future model 1. (Model 3)

For inference later I simply want to save the weights of models 1 and 2.  I have had multiple issues with this, due to what appear to be bugs in some versions of Keras (I'm using 2.2.2) and also loading the weights more explicitly is appearing to result in randomized weights and so isn't working correctly.  Instead of attempting to troubleshoot what is going wrong with whatever scenario I'm simply trying to determine what is the best practice for saving intermediate nested models.

```
def create_model_2(IN_DIM=(224, 224, 3), OUT_DIM=128):
    # First define the transfer learning model
    initial_img = Input(shape=(IN_DIM))

    black_box = MobileNetV2(include_top=False, input_shape=IN_DIM, weights="imagenet", pooling="avg")(initial_img)

    bb_model = Model(b_img, black_box)

    # freeze layers for transfer learning model
    for layer in bb_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    #########################
    ###### TOWER BLOCK ######
    #########################

    img = Input(shape=(IN_DIM))

    x = bb_model(img)

    # add some layers to try to learn
    x = Dense(64, activation='relu', name='new_fc0')(x)

    x = Dense(OUT_DIM, activation='relu', name='new_fc1')(x)

    # L2 norm to project to unit sphere
    out = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1), name='final_l2_norm')(x)

    _model_2 = Model(img, out)

    return _model_2
```

Then the structure of Model 3:

```
IN_DIM = (224, 224, 3)  # mobilenetv2=(224, 224, 3) Iv3=(299, 299, 3)
OUT_DIM = 32 

model_2 = create_model_2(IN_DIM, OUT_DIM)

# then define images for triplets
anchor_img = Input(shape=IN_DIM)
pos_img = Input(shape=IN_DIM)
neg_img = Input(shape=IN_DIM)

# create three vectors representing the images
anchor_in = model_2(anchor_img)
positive_in = model_2(pos_img)
negative_in = model_2(neg_img)

# concatenate the vectors into one large vector for input into the triplet loss "processor"
merged_vector = concatenate([anchor_in, positive_in, negative_in], axis=-1)

# actually define the model:
model_3 = Model(inputs=[anchor_img, pos_img, neg_img], outputs=merged_vector)
```

The model seems to run and train just fine:

```
OPTIMIZER = SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9)

final_model.compile(optimizer=OPTIMIZER, loss=triplet_loss, metrics=[avg_AP_dist, avg_AN_dist])

history = final_model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                                    epochs=5,  # short for debugging
                                    use_multiprocessing=True,
                                    workers=4)
```

But saving the model after training is unclear:

```
out_file = "../../models/{:}_epoch_{:}_weights.h5".format(MODEL_DESC, 5)
model_2.save_weights(out_file)  # save the actual Tower weights, discard the "booster" wrapper
print("Saved: {:}".format(out_file))
```

Or:

```
out_file = "../../models/{:}_epoch_{:}_weights.h5".format(MODEL_DESC, 5)
model_2.save(out_file)  # save the actual Tower weights, discard the "booster" wrapper
print("Saved: {:}".format(out_file))
```

Or something else?

The current failure modes seem to be if I try to load in just the weights into a newly instantiated model_2 instance I get:

```
ValueError: axes don't match array
```

Which from searching may be related to a bug in Keras.  If I save the model (.save() rather than .save_weights() then it loads without complaint but the inference is not stable and appears to be horrible/random.)

Thank you.

Still getting the following traceback:

```
<snip>/src/notebooks/vectorizer.py in load_model()
     65 
     66     # load the weights
---> 67     loaded_model.load_weights(weights_path)
     68 
     69     print("Model ready")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py in load_weights(self, filepath, by_name, skip_mismatch, reshape)
   1164             else:
   1165                 saving.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(
-> 1166                     f, self.layers, reshape=reshape)
   1167 
   1168     def _updated_config(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, layers, reshape)
   1043                                                        original_keras_version,
   1044                                                        original_backend,
-> 1045                                                        reshape=reshape)
   1046         if len(weight_values) != len(symbolic_weights):
   1047             raise ValueError('Layer #' + str(k) +

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in preprocess_weights_for_loading(layer, weights, original_keras_version, original_backend, reshape)
    680         weights = convert_nested_time_distributed(weights)
    681     elif layer.__class__.__name__ in ['Model', 'Sequential']:
--> 682         weights = convert_nested_model(weights)
    683 
    684     if original_keras_version == '1':

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in convert_nested_model(weights)
    668                     weights=weights[:num_weights],
    669                     original_keras_version=original_keras_version,
--> 670                     original_backend=original_backend))
    671                 weights = weights[num_weights:]
    672         return new_weights

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in preprocess_weights_for_loading(layer, weights, original_keras_version, original_backend, reshape)
    680         weights = convert_nested_time_distributed(weights)
    681     elif layer.__class__.__name__ in ['Model', 'Sequential']:
--> 682         weights = convert_nested_model(weights)
    683 
    684     if original_keras_version == '1':

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in convert_nested_model(weights)
    656                     weights=weights[:num_weights],
    657                     original_keras_version=original_keras_version,
--> 658                     original_backend=original_backend))
    659                 weights = weights[num_weights:]
    660 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py in preprocess_weights_for_loading(layer, weights, original_keras_version, original_backend, reshape)
    799             weights[0] = np.reshape(weights[0], layer_weights_shape)
    800         elif layer_weights_shape != weights[0].shape:
--> 801             weights[0] = np.transpose(weights[0], (3, 2, 0, 1))
    802             if layer.__class__.__name__ == 'ConvLSTM2D':
    803                 weights[1] = np.transpose(weights[1], (3, 2, 0, 1))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in transpose(a, axes)
    596 
    597     """
--> 598     return _wrapfunc(a, 'transpose', axes)
    599 
    600 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     49 def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
     50     try:
---> 51         return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
     52 
     53     # An AttributeError occurs if the object does not have

ValueError: axes don't match array
```

Comment: This solved my problem: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55855273/6013016)

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the model to JSON, and the weights in HDF5 format with `save_weights()`.

```
# save the model
model_json = model_2.to_json()
with open("model_2.json", "w") as j_file:
    j_file.write(model_json)

# save the weights
model.save_weights("model_2.h5")
```

Later to load the model:

```
# load the model
j_file = open('model_2.json', 'r')
loaded_json_model = j_file.read()
j_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_json_model)


# load the weights
loaded_model.load_weights("model_2.h5")
```

Answer (score 0):

After you've done training the model:

```py
final_model.save('model.h5')
```

To reload the model, simply use:

```py
from keras import load_model
model=load_model('model.h5')
```